# The NotEmptyValidationRule control prevents input of a float number

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a NotEmptyValidationRule class as below. If I do `Text="{Binding SelectedSpeed}"` normally, I can enter float numbers without any problem.

If you check the NotEmptyValidationRule as follows, `"."` and `","` is blocking the input. I don't understand why the problem is caused.

Thank you for answer.

**NotEmptyValidationRule.cs**

```
public class NotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? "").ToString())
            ? new ValidationResult(false, "Field is required.")
            : ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

**Xaml Code**

```
<TextBox Width="150"
         Margin="10,0,0,0"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
               <TextBox.Text>
               <Binding Path="SelectedSpeed"
                        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:NotEmptyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
               </Binding>
               </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**My View Model**

```
private float? _selectedSpeed;
public float? SelectedSpeed
    {
        get => _selectedSpeed;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedSpeed, value);
    }
```

Comment: Just a note: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value?.ToString())` is much better to read than your current `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? "").ToString())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such errors are almost always related to setting the `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` of a `TextBox.Text` binding to `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged`.
This trigger value is almost always not necessary. In the "best" scenario it results in a too chatty property, which gets even worse if setting the property also involves raising events or executing operations in general.
And in the worst case this trigger makes your `TextBox` logic fail.
You almost always want to handle the user input when the input is completed - which probably is after the user corrects his own typing errors). That's why `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus` is the default for a `TextBox.Text` binding.

Due to the `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` setting, in your case entering the value `3.3` is split into three property assignments:

1. `3`
2. `3.`
3. `3.3`

Since your property type is `float` (and not `string`), the input "breaks" at step 2): `3.` is not a valid float and will be converted to `3`, which will appear as if the `.` (decimal separator) is denied.
You can test the outcome of `Convert.ToDouble("3.")`, which is expected to return `3`.

Solutions

1. set `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` to the more reasonable and better performing `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus` value (and since this is the default for a `TextBox.Text` binding, simply don't set `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger`).
2. define the property `SelectedSpeed` of type `string`.

Comment: Really good explanation and solution. I understood the source of the problem and found the solution. Thank you.